# how to hide/show button on view condition inside mvc view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

i want to `hide/show` a `button` on `condition` but not able to do it inside view.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Mapping";
    WebGrid grid = null;
    if (ViewBag.Mappings != null)
    {
        grid = new WebGrid(source: ViewBag.Mappings,
                                defaultSort: "Id",
                                canPage: true,
                                canSort: true,
                                rowsPerPage: 10);
    }
}
<h3>@ViewData["Message"]</h3>
@if (grid != null)
{
    @grid.GetHtml(
                tableStyle: "grid",
                headerStyle: "head",
                alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("", header: null, format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Index", new { uid = (Guid)item.id, userAction = "Edit" }, new { @class = "edit" })
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Index", new { uid = (Guid)item.id, userAction = "Delete" }, new { @class = "Delete" })</text>),
                                            grid.Column("PricingSecurityID"),
                                            grid.Column("CUSIP"),
                                            grid.Column("Calculation")
                                          )

                )
}

if(@ViewBag.Mappings != null)
  {    
@Html.ActionLink("Update", "Index", new { userAction = "Update" }, new { @class = "Update" })
}
```

In the above view if `ViewBag.Mappings != null` then i'm populating webgrid.
And if webgrid is populated I need to show a `Update` button under a webgrid, but where i go wrong to achieve this in condition ?

Comment: What happens? Are the link generated anyway?

Comment: Are you setting the ViewBag.Mappings in controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the "@" on the 4th line from the bottom:

Before:

```
if(@ViewBag.Mappings != null)
```

After:

```
@if(ViewBag.Mappings != null)
```